# Help find the second derivative of a function

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, lie-algebras

If
$$
\begin{align*}
r = \frac{y}{x} & & s= -\frac{1}{y} & & \frac{ds}{dr}=\frac{y'}{r^2\left(xy'-y\right)}
\end{align*}
$$

determine $$\frac{d^2s}{dr^2}$$

**NB:** $y' = \frac{dy}{dx}$

**NB:** this is part of a greater problem regarding solving $y''=0$ using symmetry methods.

Ok so here is my attempt at this very ugly second derivative:

$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{d^2s}{dr^2} = &\frac{d}{dr}\left( \frac{y'}{ryy'-r^2y} \right) \\
\\
= & \frac{ y'' \left(ryy'-ry \right) - y'\left(yy' +r(y')^2 + ryy'' - y - ry'\right)}{\left(ryy'-ry\right)^2}\\
\\
\end{align*}
$$

Since the initial condition equation I am solving is $y''=0$ I can simplify this (ever so slightly) to get:

$$
\frac{d^2s}{dr^2} = \frac{ -y' \left( yy' +r(y')^2 -y - ry' \right)}{\left(ryy' - ry \right)^2 }\\
\\
$$

The aim is to do the following:

- let $z = \frac{ds}{dr}$
- so $\frac{d^2s}{dr^2}=\frac{dz}{dr}$
- Integrate $\frac{dz}{dr}$ to get $z$ in terms of only $r, s$ and constants
- substitute this form of $z$ into $\frac{ds}{dr}$
- integrate and solve for $s$
- substitute the given values for $s$ and $r$ in terms of $x$ and $y$
- rearrange to get an equation in the form $y=Ax+B$

Comment: What does $y'$ represent here?  $\frac{dy}{dr}$, or $\frac{dy}{dx}$, or something else?

Comment: @Strants it represents $\frac{dy}{dx}$

Answer (score 1):

$$ s\, \, x = \frac{-1}{r}$$

Differentiate w.r.t. $r$ using chain rule, using primes w.r.t $r$ only,obtaining $ s^{'}, s^{''}, r^{'}, r^{''} $ during the differerntiation.

$$ s^{'} x +s x^{'}    = \frac{1}{r^2}$$

$$ s^{''} x + 2 s^{'} x^{'}   + s x^{''}    = \frac{-2}{r^3}.$$

Comment: I tried to get the second derivative.  I didn't get any terms where I could use your hint of $srx = -1$ where am I going wrong?

Comment: Please see the  edit above.

Comment: Please see the added information to the question.

Comment: Using your second equation, can I use the following:

Comment: I need values in $s, r$ and $y$.  Using your second equation, can I use the following:$s'' = \frac{d^2s}{dr^2}$   , $s' = \frac{ds}{dr}$   , $x' = \frac{y'r-y}{r^2}$  , $x'' = \frac{y''r^2 - y'r - y''r + 2y''}{r^3}$  ?